# Pythonic way to append list within single loop

Tags: python, list

I process Word file collecting some info stored inside table. Initialy I had this:

```
table = [[app.ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(x, y).Range.Text[:-1]
 for y in [3, 4]] for x in range(13, app.ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows.Count-2)]
```

Here I get 2d list to pass further. But sometimes I get a set of tables in a single file. Structure is always the same, so I can use

```
table += ["here's the same list as above with different index in Tables"]
```

to append my list with new data and `return`.

So code is now is:

```
table = [[]]
for tab in app.ActiveDocument.Tables:
    table += [[tab.Cell(x, y).Range.Text[:-1] for y in [3, 4]] for x in range(13, tab.Rows.Count-2)]
table.remove([])
```

but PyCharm says that assigning list is not a "nice" way to get things working. Is there a more elegant way to create list and simultaneously append it in a loop? I don't see a way to let Python know that I'm working with list of items and i don't know how to pack this loop inside initial creation of `table`.

Comment: You can avoid calling `table.remove([])` if you do `table = []`

Comment: Thanks! Now I'm one step closer to simple code. And warning also vanished, looks like this solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what you are saying with `table = [[]]`is "I have a list which contains an empty list".

And with `table.remove([])` you are removing that empty list. This doesn't add anything to your program really.

You can avoid calling `table.remove([])` if you do `table = []`.

The lists you are appending in the for loop are not affected by this and the problem/warning should also be gone.

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension , but would look a bit messy -

```
table = [[[tab.Cell(x, y).Range.Text[:-1] for y in [3, 4]]
           for x in range(13, tab.Rows.Count-2) ]
           for tab in app.ActiveDocument.Tables ]
```

Comment: This way I gets 3d list, it will need more code to process further. At least there will be two loops to extract my data. But still thanks.